# Using wildcards with a LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I currently have a LinqDataSource on an ASP.NET page which is used as the data source for a FormView. I need to dynamically alter the `where` clause based on parameters that are passed through the query string. I have this working fine except that I want the end user to be able to use wildcards:

- A "?" is used to represent a single character.
- A "*" represents multiple characters.

Seems easy enough, all I need to do use the LIKE operator and replace `?` with `_` (match a single character), and `*` with `%` (match all characters).

Below is the method that does the fancy footwork (which is called on `PageLoad`), and it works great except that my wildcards are being escaped.

```
private void ApplyFilter(ref LinqDataSource lds)
{
    if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
    {
        string where = "";
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString[key] != "")
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    where += key + ".Contains(@" + key + ")";
                }
                else
                {
                    where += " AND " + key + ".Contains(@" + key + ")";
                }

                lds.WhereParameters.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key].Replace("?", "_").Replace("*", "%"));
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (where != "")
            lds.Where = where;
    }
}
```

Below is the query that is generated from this query string: `.aspx?LOOP_DESCRIPTION=*&LOOP=*&AREA=01`

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t1].[AREA], [t1].[LOOP], [t1].[LOOP DESCRIPTION] AS [LOOP_DESCRIPTION]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[AREA], [t0].[LOOP], [t0].[LOOP DESCRIPTION]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[AREA], [t0].[LOOP], [t0].[LOOP DESCRIPTION]
    FROM [dbo].[INSTRUMENT LOOP DESCRIPTION] AS [t0]
    WHERE ([t0].[LOOP DESCRIPTION] LIKE @p0 ESCAPE ''~'') AND ([t0].[LOOP] LIKE @p1 ESCAPE ''~'') AND ([t0].[AREA] LIKE @p2)
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p3 + 1 AND @p3 + @p4
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 int,@p4 int',@p0=N'%~%%',@p1=N'%~%%',@p2=N'%01%',@p3=0,@p4=1
```

As you can see by the parameter assignment, my wildcards are being escaped with the tilde character:

```
@p0=N'%~%%',@p1=N'%~%%',@p2=N'%01%'
```

My question is, is it possible to stop the `_` and `%` characters from being escaped?

Comment: please can you tell when do they get escaped

Comment: That's the query that is generated by the framework, it's escaping them somewhere internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to get this figured out. Thanks to a class from [this post](http://forums.asp.net/post/3494722.aspx), I am able to to use the LinqDataSource_Selecting event and filter my data successfully with wildcards working using this code:

```
protected void ldsData_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    var result = db.INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTIONs.AsQueryable();

    foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString[key].Trim() != "")
        {
            result = result.WhereLike(key, Request.QueryString[key].Replace("?", "_").Replace("*", "%"));
        }
    }

    e.Result = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try url decode  `Request.QueryString[key]`

Example:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString[key]);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, it's the parameter values in the generated SQL that are being escaped...

Comment: @Hoff are you posting the query back to the UI because this might cause the escaping

Comment: The only code I use is in the example above. `ApplyFilter` is called on PageLoad.