# LINQ "WhereLike" extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ, I have the need to query a table using my own wildcards (WHERE LIKE) and I couldn't use the normal `Contains` method because it kept escaping my wildcards (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512539/using-wildcards-with-a-linqdatasource/11546691)). I found an [extension method](http://forums.asp.net/post/3494722.aspx) that works flawlessly, but only on string columns:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string pattern)
{
    if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

    var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
    var prop = Expression.Property(a, propertyName);
    var body = Expression.Call(typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null, prop, Expression.Constant(pattern));
    var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, a);

    return source.Where(fn);
}
```

Here's an example of how I use the above method:

```
db.TABLE_NAME.WhereLike("COLUMN_NAME", "SEARCH%");
```

As I mentioned, this works great on a string column, but when I try to use this method on a non-string column such as an int, it blows up with the error:

`No method 'Like' on type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods' is compatible with the supplied arguments.`

This is understandable because you can't perform a LIKE operation on a non-string column, you'd have to cast or convert the data to a string first. I'm not super familiar with LINQ Expressions so I'm not sure how to modify the `WhereLike` method above to do a cast or `ToString()` first. Does anybody know I would accomplish this so I can perform a wildcard search on a non-string column?

Comment: How do you envision this working on integers, dates/times, or floating point numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure why this WhereLike is even necessary. In most cases on strings, when Linq converts to SQL, `.Contains("text")` is equivalent to `LIKE '%text%'`, `.StartsWith("text")` is equivalent to LIKE `text%`, and `.EndsWith("text") is equivalent to LIKE `%text`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, consider the following SQL on an integer column: `select * from [DSTYPE_FIELD_HEADINGS] WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar, [DATA_SHEET_TYPE]) LIKE '5_'`. @JamieSee, I can't use those methods because the user HAS to be able to enter their own wildcards, perhaps this is a better example: `db.TABLE_NAME.WhereLike("COLUMN_NAME", "TEST%TEST");`

Comment: I guess I don't understand doing string searches on integer fields (usually you do *range* queries). I guess all you want to do is blanket convert all columns to strings?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I am converting an Access app to ASP.NET so I need to retain the functionality that it has. I would never design an app that needs this functionality but unfortunately in the existing app this is possible, so I need to replicate it. 98% of the columns are strings so this isn't a problem, but there are those few that are non-string. I do need to convert all the cols to strings in LINQ but am not sure how with the extension method above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the type to string, and [L2S supports Object.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882658).

In order to use this, you'll wrap the property access expression in another method call expression:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    string propertyName,
    string pattern)
{
    if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

    var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");

    // Wrap the property access in a call to property.ToString()
    var prop = Expression.Property(a, propertyName);
    var conv = Expression.Call(prop, "ToString", null);

    // Basically: SqlMethods.Like(Convert.ToString([prop]), pattern)
    var body = Expression.Call(
        typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null,
        conv,
        Expression.Constant(pattern));

    var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, a);

    return source.Where(fn);
}
```

Comment: This compiles, however it throws the exception: `More than one method 'ToString' on type 'System.Convert' is compatible with the supplied arguments.` when I call WhereLike, even on string columns. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hoff: try it now, it switches to just calling `object.ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the last line to:

```
return source.Select(t => t.ToString()).Where(fn);
```

**EDIT:**

Is this what you try after my comments?

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereLike<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string pattern)
{
  if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

  var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "a");
  var prop = Expression.Property(a, propertyName);
  var body = Expression.Call(typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null, prop, Expression.Constant(pattern));
  var fn = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(body, a);

  return source.Select(t => t.ToString()).Where(fn);
}
```

Comment: This results in 2 compilation errors: 1. `'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,int,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments` and `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<string,int,bool>>'
`

Comment: @Hoff Hmm, OK. That's because after my select method, we have an `IQueryable<string>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>` like before. If you keep my `Select` **and** replace all occurrences of `T` in the body of your method with `string`, then there's a good chance it will work. (Again I haven't tested it.) But as JamieSee has mentioned in a comment to your question, maybe you don't need this `WhereLike` method at all.

Comment: That code still fails to compile, @sixlettervariables' code did the trick though. Thank you for your help though!