# DropDownList value is blank when saving a FormView's filtered result

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, formview, linqdatasource

I have a FormView that is used for viewing, editing and inserting items into a MSSQL database. The FormView is wired up to a LinqDataSource, and I use its `Selecting` event to filter the data displayed in the FormView based on parameters (columns) passed in the query string.

In the FormView I have a DropDownList that displays values from a related table. Everything works as it should except when I try to edit - for some reason, the selected value of the DropDownList is always empty when I try to save the edit (even when I have a value selected). The insert works as it should.

I have traced the problem down to my `Selecting` event where I do the filtering. If I comment out the method that does the filtering, it updates the item successfully - but I can't figure out why the filtering is breaking the update.

Here is my (shortened) FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvData" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ldsData" 
    ondatabound="fvData_DataBound">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <table class="pad5">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">AREA:</td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="cboAREA" runat="server" DataTextField="AREA_NAME" DataValueField="AREA1" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AREA") %>' DataSourceID="ldsAreas" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">LOOP:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLOOP" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LOOP") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">LOOP DESCRIPTION:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLOOP_DESCRIPTION" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("LOOP_DESCRIPTION") %>' style="width: 600px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CausesValidation="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <table class="pad5">
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">AREA:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboAREA" runat="server" DataTextField="AREA_NAME" 
                        DataValueField="AREA1" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AREA") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="ldsAreas">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">LOOP:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLOOP" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LOOP") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="field-name">LOOP DESCRIPTION:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLOOP_DESCRIPTION" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("LOOP_DESCRIPTION") %>' style="width: 600px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" CausesValidation="True" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The LinqDataSource:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsData" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="E_and_I.EAndIDataDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
    EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTIONs" onselecting="ldsData_Selecting" OrderBy="ID ASC" >
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

My `ldsData_Selecting` method:

```
protected void ldsData_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    EI.FilterData<INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTION>(ref e, db.INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTIONs, this.db);
}
```

And finally `EI.FilterData`:

```
public static void FilterData<T>(ref LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e, IEnumerable<T> source, EAndIDataDataContext db)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
    {
        var result = source.AsQueryable();
        bool filtered = false;

        // get column names
        var columnNames = db.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(EAndIDataDataContext)).GetMetaType(typeof(T)).DataMembers;

        foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            string val = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[key];

            // check the query string key exists as a column in the table, etc
            if (columnNames.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == key) != null && val.Trim() != "" && val != "*")
            {
                result = result.WhereLike(key, val.Replace("?", "_").Replace("*", "%"));
                filtered = true;
            }
        }

        if (filtered)
            e.Result = result;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason filtering the results would break the update (and ONLY the DropDownList's - textboxes work fine)? The filtering works perfectly (that is, the FormView only shows the records based parameters entered by the user); if you're wondering what the `WhereLike` extension method does, you can check out [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512539/using-wildcards-with-a-linqdatasource) answer.

Comment: Try to write filter code in ldsData_Selecting handler and see what happen? I think something is *wrong* with `ondatabound="fvData_DataBound"`

Comment: The filter code is only being executed in the `ldsData_Selecting` event, not `fvData_DataBound`. The `fvData_DataBound` event just sets a label in the FormView if it is in ReadOnly mode.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you post data with editing, you re bind your data and so you erase the selected Value.

Solution : Adjust your bind

```
If( !  IsPostBack)
{
  //Here realize your bind of data

}
```

In order to persist your datas, use ViewState

With this solution When you post you don't re bind data, and so ViewState contains your selected value

Comment: If this was the case why would the insert work? Also I've tried using `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` but then the filtering only works on the first page load. When you switch modes in the FormView the filtering no longer works because of the PostBack.

Comment: insert work that's normal, because you bind you datas Hoff each time, but when you select data on control this data is saved on viewstate, when you re bind you erase

Comment: You try with ! IsPostBack but this time you set EnableViewState="true" on your control

Comment: EnableViewState defaults to true

Comment: Right but i think that you adjust in another code to false in order to optimize

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in the drop-down lists for your two cases, which I think is probably the cause of this.  For Insert, you have AppendDataBoundItems="true", while for the Update form above it, this flag is not set (and it defaults to false).  What that means in terms of the submitting form is that, for the Insert form, when it's rebinding it appends the items to the current list instead of clearing them; but for the Update form, because it's not set to append, it will clear the items and THEN binds them -- so the Binding is happening in both cases, but in the case of the Update form, it's clearing the items when that happens and giving you blank data.

Instead of just rejecting the filtering on Postback, which causes your form to fail eventually, I would instead filter based on the control that CAUSED the Postback.  At the top of the function you can capture the control ID that caused the postback, and then you can filter only when it isn't a postback coming from the buttons that are triggering the data storage step.  If that's in place, I believe you should be able to do away with the AppendDataBoundItems flags altogether.

A code snippet update of what I mean:

```
string initControl = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];
if (!IsPostBack || (initControl != "btnInsert" && initControl != "btnUpdate") {
    // code here
}
```

What this does is expand the check for PostBack so that the conditions are allowed EITHER if not a post back (which you tested previously), but critically, it'll also allow the lists to update if the form IS posted back, so long as the control posting back isn't one that is triggering an event dependent on the contents of those bound elements.  That should mean that you avoid the problem of it only working for the first page load.

Additionally, if you need the control to bind regardless, you could add a global boolean variable to the script; set it to False by default, and then set it to True if the above condition is not met (i.e., if you're preventing the binding).  Then you can check that boolean value in the Page_PreRender function, and if it's set to true, you can perform a late binding of the control at that step (which will only fire after the Insert/Update events have already processed, so any binding at that point will no longer affect the result of the form processing).

Comment: In the event ldsData_Selecting, before the function is called to check the query string, you should be able to check and see if a) it is a post-back, as the previous reply suggested, and b) if it is, what control triggered the post-back.  (The basics of this are in checking Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] -- there are some foibles, but that's the key.)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, unfortunately it's still not working. I did however find out another vital piece to this puzzle though. The bug **only** happens when there is one record in the FormView. The reason everything is working properly when I remove the filter method is because it then pulls back everything, not just the filtered result. I can't believe I didn't see this earlier. Still not sure how to fix it though.